# How to examine verbose output after execution in Langchain

Tags: debugging, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I have a starter code to run an agent with retrieval_qa chain. The agent has verbose=True parameter and I can see the conversation happening in console.
How can I see the whole conversation if I want to analyze it after the agent.run command is executed. I am working in a notebook.

```
retrieval_qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type = 'stuff',
    retriever = db.as_retriever()
)

tools = [Tool(
    name = 'QA System',
    func = retrieval_qa.run,
    description = 'Useful for answering questions'
)]

agent = initialize_agent(
    llm=llm,
    tools=tools,
    agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    verbose = True
)
# agent.max_iterations = 2
# %%
response = agent.run("What do monkeys eat for breakfast?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this info through return_intermediate_steps=True,

```
agent = initialize_agent(
tools,
llm,
agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
verbose=True,
return_intermediate_steps=True,
)

details = response["intermediate_steps"]
```

You can print or write this to file for you further analysis